# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException when reading an element using pythonanywhere server

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pythonanywhere, timeoutexception

I've been trying to read an element in social website with selenium with below code fragment.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(urls)
read_text = WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).text
```

The program runs perfectly fine in the local machine. But when I run it in pythonanywhere server I get following error.

> read_text = WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).text
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpl7fmm68q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
>       at FirefoxDriver.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpl7fmm68q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
>       at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpl7fmm68q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>       at DelayedCommand.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpl7fmm68q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>       at DelayedCommand.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpl7fmm68q/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Why do I get this error when I run the program in pythonanywhere server but not when I run it in local machine? How to solve this?

Comment: Likely your IP address from `pythonanywhere` is blocked and can't access the website you're trying to reach. I've already experimented this issue with PA. Try something like `browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')` to find out what is going on...

Comment: If you are on the free account you may access only the [whitelisted](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) sites.

Comment: I was trying to access to a whitelisted site

Comment: print out the browser body to see what is in it?

Comment: yeah did it as suggested by @Neroksi. Seems he is correct